# Excel VBA Range.Find Issues with format matching

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried numerous things but `Range.Find` returns "Apr" not found. Apr is in E17, so it exists as can be seen here:

[image: The table to which the data is being posted]

I am trying to do the following:

1. Copy data from external xlsx monthly file into a sheet named "New Data".
2. Paste some of that data into a summary sheet "Year Summary". [Note using Excel formulas would clear previous months' data so that was tried and rejected.]
3. The pasted data needs to go in places specified by the month - so April's data in a column below "Apr".
4. The imported data has a cell with reference to the month: for example the **text** "For the month ended [30th April 2021]"
5. I copy that cell to P7 on the summary sheet and extract the month name into cell Q8 on the summary sheet (formula is `=MID(P7,24,3)`. Result = "Apr"
6. I have tried formatting that as Text or Number, including `=Text(=MID(P7,24,3),"MMM")`.
7. I have changed the format of E17 (the cell that has "Apr" in it and below which I want to paste my new data, to text and number but `Find` does not find it though both say "Apr" in the two cells!

I have pared back the code to the main issue which reads:

```vb
Sub Add_Data()
    Dim LkpValue As String
    Dim rgFound As Variant
    'Dim LkpRange As Range

    LkpValue = Worksheets("Data").Range("Q8").Value
    'Set LkpRange = Worksheets("Data").Range("B17:M17")

    Set rgFound = Worksheets("Data").Range("B17:M17").Find(What:=LkpValue,   LookIn:=xlFormulas, Lookat:=xlPart, SearchFormat:=False).Address

    If rgFound Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("rgFound was not found")       
    Else
        MsgBox ("rgFound")
    End If
End Sub
```

I have tried defining the search range and not (as can be seen with it commented out), adding and subtracting the different parts of the `Find` parameters, all to no avail. The best I get is "Aprwasn't found" or errors 91 or 424.

I am guessing Find cannot find "Apr" in the range because it cannot see it in the right format. But how to match the formats? Any ideas anyone?

Many thanks.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the `.Find` line and check the value of `LkpValue` in the locals window.  Also, in the immediate window, at the break, type `?[E17]` `<return>` and report what that shows.

Comment: `Set rgFound = ... .Address` is not going to work. The `.Address` needs to be removed. Then you need to replace `xlFormulas` with `xlValues`, and check what E17 actually contains.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thanks. LkpValue = "Apr" in Locals window; and ?[E17] = Apr. Do the quotes mean anything in this context?

Comment: @GSerg - thanks for thoughts - I had tried with and without Address and both with and without both xlFormulas and XlValues.

Comment: No, the string will display without the quotes in the immediate window, and with the quotes in the locals window as you show. This points to a problem with your code. Not the format of the cells.  But with your code and data as shown, I would expect that your `Set rgFound = ...` line would return an error 91. Are you providing the full story here?

Comment: Oh, and for E17, also ensure that `?[E17].Value2` also returns just `Apr`

Comment: Thanks guys - I have solved it from your help.  Immediate and Locals windows v helpful. It was the formula in the sheet. Silly me I had typed 1, 2, 3, etc and in the row below turned that to Jan, Feb etc using =Text(cell, "mmm") and believed it was text!  When replaced with Jan, Feb etc as text (no formula) .Find could find it! Thanks for putting me on right track